# how to create an xml using xml writer without declaration element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlwriter

I am using `XmlWriter.Create()` to get a writer instance then write the XML, but the result has the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>`, how do I tell my xml writer do not produce it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [`XmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration).

Don't forget to set [`XmlWriterSettings.ConformanceLevel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.conformancelevel) to `ConformanceLevel.Fragment`.

Comment: From the docs you link to: `The XML declaration is always written if ConformanceLevel is set to Document, even if OmitXmlDeclaration is set to true`

Comment: Won't it be set to Document most of the time?

Comment: @Cameron, Strange question... `ConformanceLevel.Document` is default, but you can set `ConformanceLevel.Fragment`...

Comment: Ah, yes, I understand know :-) You might want to add that into your answer. What about if you want the Document conformance level (e.g. to ensure a single root node), but no XML declaration?

Comment: @Cameron, I think you answered your your question yourself :-)

Comment: Kirill, forgive my ignorance, but how did @Cameron answer the question himself?

Comment: @ro͢binmckenzie: Oh, it looks like I literally answered this question with an alternate solution (below).

Comment: In .NET Core 3.1 at least, using `OmitXmlDeclaration = false` with `ConformanceLevel.Default` works fine and no XML Declaration header is written (when using `XmlDocument.Save`).

Answer (score 6):

You can subclass `XmlTextWriter` and override the `WriteStartDocument()` method to do nothing:

```
public class XmlFragmentWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    // Add whichever constructor(s) you need, e.g.:
    public XmlFragmentWriter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding) : base(stream, encoding)
    {
    }

    public override void WriteStartDocument()
    {
       // Do nothing (omit the declaration)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new XmlFragmentWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
// Use the writer ...
```

Reference: This [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/XmlFragmentWriterOmitingTheXmlDeclarationAndTheXSDAndXSINamespaces.aspx) from Scott Hanselman.

Comment: thanks, any better way? I do not want to subclass just for the purpose of removing the declaration.

Comment: @ninithepug: Not as far as I know, sorry. You can wrap it up in a static method somewhere if you use it often, though. That should help keep it clean

Comment: @ninithepug: It seems Kirill's answer (which doesn't need a new class) might be better (unless you want the Document conformance level, of course).

Answer (score 2):

you can use `XmlWriter.Create()` with:

```
new XmlWriterSettings { 
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true, 
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment 
}

    public static string FormatXml(string xml)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml))
            return string.Empty;

        try
        {
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.LoadXml(xml);
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(
                memoryStream, 
                new XmlWriterSettings { 
                    Encoding = Encoding.Unicode, 
                    OmitXmlDeclaration = true, 
                    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment, 
                    Indent = true, 
                    NewLineOnAttributes = false }))
            {
                document.WriteContentTo(writer);
                writer.Flush();
                memoryStream.Flush();
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                {
                    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (XmlException ex)
        {
            return "Unformatted Xml version." + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Unformatted Xml version." + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```